# Login after signup in identity server4

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to login user as soon as he/she registers.

below is the scenario

1)Registration page is not on identity server.

2)Post user details to Id server from UI for user creation.

3)On successful user creation login the user and redirect.

4)Trying to do it on native app.

I tried it with javascript app but redirection fails with 405 options call.
(tried to redirect to /connect/authorize)

on mobile app, don't want user to login again after signup for UX.

Has anyone implemented such behavior

tried following [benfoster](https://benfoster.io/blog/identity-server-post-registration-sign-in)

Comment: There is no api in Identity Server 4 to `POST` user registration details.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius We have our own server on which identity server4 is used

Comment: There is not even a question in your "question". You should try and outline exactly what kind of issue you are having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so finally i was able to get it working with authorization code flow

- Whenever user signs up generate and store a otp against the newly created user.
- send this otp in post response.
- use this otp in acr_value e.g acr_values=otp:{{otpvalue}} un:{{username}}
- client then redirects to /connect/authorize with the above acr_values

below is the identity server code which handles the otp flow

```
public class SignupFlowResponseGenerator : AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator
{
    public readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;


    public SignupFlowResponseGenerator(ISystemClock clock,
        ILogger<AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator> logger,
        IConsentService consent,
        IProfileService profile,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(clock, logger, consent, profile)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override async Task<InteractionResponse> ProcessInteractionAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request, ConsentResponse consent = null)
    {
        var processOtpRequest = true;

        var isAuthenticated = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        // if user is already authenticated then no need to process otp request.
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            processOtpRequest = false;
        }
        // here we only process only the request which have otp
        var acrValues = request.GetAcrValues().ToList();
        if (acrValues == null || acrValues.Count == 0)
        {
            processOtpRequest = false;
        }

        var otac = acrValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("otp:"));
        var un = acrValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("un:"));

        if (otac == null || un == null)
        {
            processOtpRequest = false;
        }

        if (processOtpRequest)
        {
            var otp = otac.Split(':')[1];
            var username = un.Split(':')[1];

            // your logic to get and check opt against the user
            // if valid then 
            if (otp == { { otp from db for user} })
            {

                // mark the otp as expired so that it cannot be used again.

                var claimPrincipal = {{build your principal}};

                request.Subject = claimPrincipal ;

                await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync({{your auth scheme}}, claimPrincipal , null);

                return new InteractionResponse
                {
                    IsLogin = false, // as login is false it will not redirect to login page but will give the authorization code
                    IsConsent = false
                };
            }
        }

        return await base.ProcessInteractionAsync(request, consent);
    }
}
```

dont forget to add the following code in startup

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator<SignupFlowResponseGenerator>()
```

Comment: so after using this solution, the mobile app client will get the token as http response for the signup request . right ?

Comment: Yes the mobile app will get the authorization code from above code and then it can exchange the code to get the actual token (/connect/token) .

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using IdentityServerTools class that IdentityServer4 provide to help issuing a JWT token For a Client OR a User (in your case)

So after the user signs up, you already have all claims needed for generating the token for the user:
including but not limited to: userid, clientid , roles, claims, auth_time, aud, scope.

You most probably need refresh token if you use hybrid flow which is the most suitable one for mobile apps.

In the following example, I am assuming you are using ASP.NET Identity for Users. The IdentityServer4 Code is still applicable regardless what you are using for users management.

```
public Constructor(                UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IClientStore clientStore,
            IdentityServerTools identityServerTools,
            IRefreshTokenService refreshTokenService)
{// minimized for clarity}

public async Task GenerateToken(ApplicationUser user
                )
            {

                var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);    
                var claims = new List<Claim>(principal.Claims);
                var client = await clientStore.FindClientByIdAsync("client_Id");
                // here you should add all additional claims like clientid , aud , scope, auth_time coming from client info
                // add client id 
                claims.Add(new Claim("client_id", client.ClientId));

                // add authtime
                claims.Add(new Claim("auth_time", $"{(Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds}"));

                // add audiences
                var audiences = client.AllowedScopes.Where(s => s != "offline_access" && s != "openid" && s != "profile");
                foreach (var audValue in audiences)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim("aud", audValue));
                }

                // add /resources to aud so the client can get user profile info.
                var IdentityServiceSettings = _configuration.GetSection("IdentityService").Get<IdentityServiceConsumeSettings>();
                claims.Add(new Claim("aud", $"{IdentityServiceUrl}/resources"));

                //scopes for the the what cook user
                foreach (var scopeValue in client.AllowedScopes)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim("scope", scopeValue));
                }

                //claims.Add(new Claim("scope", ""));
                claims.Add(new Claim("idp", "local"));
                var accesstoken = identityServerTools.IssueJwtAsync(100, claims);

                var t = new Token
                {
                    ClientId = "client_id",
                    Claims = claims
                };


                var refereshToken = refreshTokenService.CreateRefreshTokenAsync(principal, t, client);

            }
```

This is just a code snippet that needs some changes according to your case

Comment: I actually thought of this but the only question is does it honor oauth2

Comment: Could you clarify more your comment.

Comment: Guess, the OP mentioned that in your picture you missed the OpenId Connet session, so you downgraded your "protocol simulation" to a kind of OAuth. That's why this's not the answer.